# PHP creating slugify (clean URL) links in simple way? iconv malfunction?

Tags: php, url, seo, iconv, clean-urls

I think this is the simplest way to slugify urls. You have any contra-indication?

```php
function url_clean($str)
{
   $str = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);
   $clean_str = preg_replace(array(
      '/\'|\"/',
      '/ /'
   ) , array(
      '',
      '-'
   ) , $str);
   return $clean_str;
}
```

**UPDATE**

the code above working great on local, but on the server return string with `?` instead of transliterated characters: `árvíztűrő` -> `?rv?zt?r?`

`phpinfo()` on localhost

> iconv support     enabled
>
> iconv implementation  "libiconv"
>
> iconv library version     1.14

`phpinfo()` on server

> iconv support     enabled
>
> iconv implementation  glibc
>
> iconv library version     2.12

Comment: What if `$str` contains e.g. `%30` (or any other url-encoded character)? What if it contains characters invalid in a URL but part of ASCII?

Comment: Maybe this is better suited on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Made for creating SEO friendly urls, in this case can't see the problem. But you are right. How can i make more efficient?

Comment: I woudn't rely on iconv to do proper transliteration. Use [urlify](https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify) or [see this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php#110598)

Comment: @OneTrickPony i think these are easy and great solutions, but on a webpage (unlike portals or cms sites) doesn't needed so many resource use. Am i rigth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You! 
Finally this is my solution without that [buggy iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
function url_clean($str) {
    $accent = array(' ','ű','á','é','ú','ő','ó','ü','ö','í','Ű','Á','É','Ú','Ő','Ó','Ü','Ö','Í');
    $clean = array('-','u','a','e','u','o','o','u','o','i','U','A','E','U','O','O','U','O','I');
    $str = str_replace($accent, $clean, $str);
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-.]/', '', $str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your previous function is much better than the one in the response (more cases). The problem is with the locale. Try to add the next line **before** the function definition:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF8');
```

(*es_ES* is my locale, but yours may be different).